# How do you apply a CSS style to a asp:GridView?

Tags: css, asp.net, gridview

Can someone please point me in the direction of some documentation re. applying a CSS style to a row in an ASP GridView ?

I have created an inherited GridView control so that I can raise a "RowClicked" event. This works fine. I would, however, like to highlight the row which the user has clicked. Coming from a Windows programming stand point, I would just give my GridView control a method similar to the following:

```
    public void HighlightRow(GridViewRow row)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow r in this.Rows)
        {
            r.BackColor = (r == row ? System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue : System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window);
        }
    }
```

This also works fine, but doesn't seem to play with CSS *(not that I expect it to)*. I've tried adding random guesses to the "style.css" file, but nothing seems to work. I've looked at the source of the rendered page, and see that its really a table with a <tr> tag, but I don't really know what syntax to put into style.css to get the row to highlight. I know I should set the ".CssStyle" property on the GridViewRow object - but to what ?

I have this in my page.aspx file:

```
<rac:MyGridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ... CssClass="mGrid" >
:
```

and this in my style.css file:

```
.mGrid .fred tr
{
    background-color:Red;
}
```

and my code does this:

```
    public void HighlightRow(GridViewRow row)
    {
        row.CssClass = "fred";
        //foreach (GridViewRow r in this.Rows)
        //{
        //    r.BackColor = (r == row ? System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue : System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window);
        //}
    }
```

Can someone please show me an example. Just as an aside, is it normal that in order to work out what to put in the CSS file, you have to render the page, and then look at the source to find out what kind of HTML the ASP has been rendered as *(and then try and guess the tag to style from there)* ?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I have just changed my code so that, in my "RowClicked" code, I set the "SelectedRow" of the grid. I can then use the "SelectedRowStyle-BackColor" attribute and, sure enough, I get the selected/clicked row highlighted without any extra code. Still can't get it to work with a CSS though.

Comment: Might help you...[ASP.NET GridView makeover using CSS](http://atashbahar.com/post/GridView-makeover-using-CSS.aspx), [Style GridView and Pager with custom css in simple steps](http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Style-GridView-and-Pager-with-custom-css-in-simple)

Comment: wouldn't it be `tr.fred` rather than `.fred tr` - from your code it looks like you are adding the class to the row